# Bootstrap dropmenu gets hidden behind content instead of pushing it down

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a dropdown menu and a submenu. Submenu expands behind the content instead of pushing it down.

I can't figure out which of the following is causing it:

```
bootstrap.css
style.css
bootstrap-responsive.css
```

I'm learning html/css/bootstrap on the fly and I've been googling and trying solutions for hours straight to no avail.

The height is always computed to 160px which isn't in any of the code.

I've tried setting z-index where possible and making height: auto. But maybe I'm not setting it at the right places.

How can I narrow down the culprit?

Thanks SO.

Attaching the screenshots.

[image: top level menu]

Query should open submenus and push down the content by design.

But..

[image: submenu is hidden]

Submenu is getting hidden.
Chrome debugger tells me the problem but I have no idea where to change it?

[image: Chrome debugger]

Please let me know what else u need me to provide

Comment: Seems like you are an user of SO for some time now. You should know that we can;t help you if you don;t share a working snippet with your code that recreates the problem

Comment: Your images won't help us help you. Need code to recreate. Could be floats not clearing, could be incorrect inline styles, could be North Korea taking over www.

Comment: I'll come up with a working snippet and share it. Apologies. Will update post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upgraded from bootstrap 2.3.1 to bootstrap 3.2.1. It's no longer an issue in bootstrap 3.2.1. The section with the issue is in

> /* ========================================================================
>    * Bootstrap: collapse.js v3.3.7
>    * http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#collapse
>    * ========================================================================
>    * Copyright 2011-2016 Twitter, Inc.
>    * Licensed under MIT (https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/master/LICENSE)
>    * ======================================================================== */

Too many changes compared to 2.3.1 and also in the section:

> // CSS TRANSITION SUPPORT (Shoutout: http://www.modernizr.com/)
>     // ============================================================

I've diff'd the old and new, made some substitution to narrow down to these 2 subsections. No idea which exact line fixed it in the latest version.

Maybe someone who's experienced enough can eventually play around and post a better answer.